# Enter login data, send to server via AJAX and show result

Tags: php, jquery

On a form I have a POP-up form. I use that form to LOGIN-box. In the box I enter a userlogin and a password. Then I click button "loggin" to close the pop-up and 
the USERLOGIN and PASSWORD is then transferred to my server for verification and the result is shown as (a) valid user ("bruger").

But I can't get a proper result from the server (probably because I am using a wrong syntax). But I don't know how to correct it.

Any help to correct this will be highly appreciated.

Here is the codes:  I click a button- a POP-UP pops up:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#loggin").on('click', function()
    {

var username = $('#muser').val();
var password = $('#mpasw').val();


//      str = $("#muser").val() + ";;" + $('#mpasw').val();
//      alert($("#muser").val() + " -- " + $('#mpasw').val() + " -- " + str);
        $("#popup-overlay").css({ visibility: "hidden"});
        $("#popup-content").css({ visibility: "hidden"});

        $(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'getdata.php',
            data: ({username:username, password: password },
            success: function(data) 
            {
          //      alert(data);
                $('#bruger').text(data);
            }
        });
      });
    });
});
```

and the server-file is this:

```
<?php
//
//  TESTING , IF LOGIN DATA ENTERS CORRECTLY ..
//
//  IF YES,  OPEN DATABASE AND LOCATE USER.. AND RETURN USER 
//  
//  will be implemented later - tests for now...
//

if($_POST["username"] === null)
{
    $username = "";
}
else
{
    $username = $_POST["username"];
}

if($_POST["password"] === null)
{
    $password = "";
}
else
{
    $password = $_POST["password"];
}

    echo 'Bruger: OLE-BOLE "'.$password.'"'; 

exit;
?>
```

Comment: When uncommenting `alert(data);` are you getting expected result?

Comment: examined code, and discovered a TYPO -->>  . data: ({username:username, password: password },       SHOULD BE :    data: ({username:username, password: password }   )   ,  // missing ' ) '...  . It works now.   SOrry the inconvinience.

Comment: try to use the html() or append() function instead of text() and see if it works.

Comment: I'm curious about the typo

Comment: @Nilesh Jain:   Changed '  text  ' to ' html '  : works perfectly.